# Cannot get div element by id

Tags: c#, html, web

This is the code, it never works

```
WebBrowser wb;
HtmlElement HTMLAuthor;
string author = " ";
try
{
     wb = new WebBrowser();
     wb.Url = new Uri(website);
     HTMLAuthor = wb.Document.GetElementById("author");
     author = Convert.ToString(HTMLAuthor);
}
catch
{
     MessageBox.Show("Could not get author info");
}
```

This is the div in the html page

```
<div id="author">Mark</div>
```

This is a Windows Form application, maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: add an explicit wait maybe before looking for "author"

Comment: it doesn't work, the messagebox doesn't show up after 1 second but it shows up instantly.

Comment: what website do you want to access ,is there any access issue .Have you opened that link in web browser (without executing)

Comment: What exactly does *it doesn't work* mean? When the messagebox pops up, an exception was thrown. What is this exception?

Comment: What webpage is it that you are trying to get the author info from? Is the author information available directly in the element with id "author" or is it nested in some further tags? Please edit your question and paste that section of the html for us to help you better

Comment: NullReferenceException, it doesn't find the id I guess, website works fine.

Comment: I added it and it's not nested in other tags.

Comment: Do you have a `<iframe>` on your website ?

Answer (score 1):

You must add an handler to event [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 wb.Navigated += wb_Navigated;
```

Then in the method body, when the document is fully loaded, you can retrieve the value of the element:

```
void wb_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    var HTMLAuthor = wb.Document.GetElementById("author");
    var author = Convert.ToString(HTMLAuthor);
}
```

Comment: [It's not correct.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/7b13a310-c5ca-4aeb-9b0e-3ade2eb8e94a/confusing-webbrowserdocumentcompleted-and-navigated)

Comment: @SerG you're right, even so the `Navigated` event works fine for getting html.

Answer (score 0):

Make any interaction with document only on  [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Comment: It doesn't give any errors now but when it's done the string is "System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement"

Comment: It's the other question. You need InnerText property of XmlElement instead of Convert.ToString().